# Не работает сложение в калькуляторе c++ через if и else if

Tags: c++, if

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    char doing;
    double a,b,summ;
    cout << "Vvedite a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Vvedite b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Vvedite deistvie * ili + ili - ili / ";
    cin >> doing;
    if (doing == '*') {
       summ = a*b;
    }  else if (doing == '/' ){
       summ = a/b;
    }  else if (doing == '+ '){
       summ = a+b;
    }  else if (doing == '-'){
       summ = a-b;
    }
    
    cout << "summa = " << summ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\Безымянный1.cpp  [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

При выполнении деление, умножение и вычитание работают прекрасно, но при сложении выводится странное число.

Comment: `'+ '` → `'+'`.

Answer (score 0):

### Вместо

```cpp
else if (doing == '+ ')
```

### Напишите так

```cpp
else if (doing == '+')
```

Компилятор не может преобразовать тип `string` в `char`